# Python look-behind regex issue: Invalid regular expression: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern

Tags: python, regex, calibre

I need to match a linebreak in-between double quotes, as in:

```
<p class="calibre1">“This is the first sentence.</p>
<p class="calibre1">And this is the second!”</p>
```

This would match `</p> <p class="calibre1">`

Now, I got this working with the regex `(?<=“[^”]*)</p>\s*<p[^>]*>(?!“)` but I get the error described in the title: "*Invalid regular expression: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern*" when I try to use it non-manually. I need this regex for the eBook management/editing program, Calibre, which uses Python for its regex engine. The regex above works for manually searching a book, but when I try to include the regex as a "common option" (run on each eBook conversion) I get that error.

I don't see how it's possible to do this without a variable width look-behind, since you can't know how long it will be from the left doublequote to the linebreak. Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: And before you continue, please consider that HTML is not a regular language so unless you are parsing a minimal subset of the language, try to use something other than regular expressions.

Comment: @msvalkon There aren't any other options, since as I said, I'm using Calibre, an eBook editing program. There is no option but to use regular expressions for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python `re` module, as most languages (with the notable exception of .NET), doesn't support variable length lookbehind.

Can't you use a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead ?

```
“[^”]*(</p>\s*<p[^>]*>)
```

Data in the [first capturing group](http://regex101.com/r/iE2lU8).

Comment: Good idea! It isn't very pretty, but matching `“([^”]*)</p>\s*<p[^>]*>(?!“)` and replacing with `“\1` seems to work.

Comment: @Zajora Oh, so that's what you wanted to do? Btw, `<p[^>]*>(?!“)` means "`<p...>` tags not followed *directly* by a `“`". Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah. It does seem a bit weird, but I had to add `(?!“)` since some eBooks have the quotes reversed (probably some kind of conversion error).. or at least, I think that was the issue. Now that I'm looking at it I'm starting to wonder..

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed.